# How to use array_multisort against two + one arrays, by sorting by the sums of the array keys?

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

For example, if these were my arrays:

```
array (4) {
  [0] => 6,
  [1] => 7,
  [2] => 8,
  [3] => 9
}
```

And:

```
array (4) {
  [0] => 10,
  [1] => 1,
  [2] => 3,
  [3] => 5
}
```

And this array, which I want to sort:

```
array (4) {
  [0] => 'foo1',
  [1] => 'foo2',
  [2] => 'foo3',
  [3] => 'foo4'
}
```

I would get this for the final result (after sorting):

```
array (4) {
  [0] => 'foo1',
  [1] => 'foo4',
  [2] => 'foo3',
  [3] => 'foo2'
}
```

Is this possible? Note that I got this final array by sorting the 3rd array provided by the sums of the same keys of the first two arrays.

Any help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$arr1 = array(6,7,8,9);
$arr2 = array(10,1,3,5);
$arr3 = array('foo1','foo2','foo3','foo4');
$arr = array();

foreach($arr1 as $key => $item){
    $arr[] = $arr1[$key]  + $arr2[$key];
}
arsort($arr);

$res = array();
foreach($arr as $key => $value){
    $res[] = $arr3[$key];
}

print_r($res);
```

Comment: thanks very much, but is there also a way to sort `$arr1` and `$arr2` as well, based on their sums? thanks.

Answer (score 0):

you can also try like this

```
$arr1 = array(6,7,8,9);
$arr2 = array(10,1,3,5);
$arr3 = array('foo1','foo2','foo3','foo4');
    foreach($arr1 as $key => $val){
        $arr2[$key] += $arr1[$key];
    }

    $arr = array_multisort($arr2, $arr3);
    $arr3 = array_reverse($arr3);
    print_r($arr3);
```